# How does javascript evaluate an if statement without a clear true or false?

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing lots of code like this in javascript:

```
if (user.length) {
  console.log("test");
}
```

I thought .length just returns a number so what does an if statement do if it gets a number? I assumed it would evealuate to false because it didn't get a clear true, but I have seen lots of this. Is it the same as saying if user.length is not undefined? How does it evaluate that, and if that is the short version what would be the long way of writing that if statement?

Comment: This will work, as described in Suresh's answer. I do, however, much prefer explicit code, i.e. `if (user.length > 0)`. It makes the code much clearer

Answer (score 5):

[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, **0**, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

So zero inside if evaluates to false.

Comment: or, `falsey` :p

Comment: @sureshatta you mean, Truthy? Lol

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes. Absolutely :D.